# ORA-00904: : invalid identifier while trying to create a table although no reserve keywords are used

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table, ora-00904

```
create table LPU_Employee (
    UID       decimal(6)  not null primary key,
    EName     varchar(30) not null,
    Hire_Date date        not null,
    Deparment varchar(30) null,
    HOD       varchar(30) null,
    HOD_UID   decimal(6)  not null,
    Salary    double      null
);
```

Answer (score 1):

- `UID` is a reserved word. Use either a different column name or put it into double quotes
- `double` is not recognised (sorry, I spell it the British way) as a data type. Use `float` .

```
create table LPU_Employee (
    "UID"     decimal(6)  not null primary key,
    EName     varchar(30) not null,
    Hire_Date date        not null,
    Deparment varchar(30) null,
    HOD       varchar(30) null,
    HOD_UID   decimal(6)  not null,
    Salary    FLOAT      null
);
```

Comment: `float` with no precision is an alias for the more commonly used `number`. `float(n)` is a way to specify precision in a more obscure way, e.g. `123.456` requires `float(17)` for some reason. Probably `number` would be more easily understood, or something like `number(8,2)` or `number(*,2)` if you want to specify an amount of money with two decimal digits.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your direct question is about UID.  I would strongly recommend *renaming* the column to avoid the conflict.  But I have other suggestions as well:

```
create table LPU_Employee (
    employee_UID decimal(6) not null primary key,
    EName     varchar(30) not null,
    Hire_Date date        not null,
    Deparment varchar2(30) null,
    HOD       varchar2(30) null,
    HOD_UID   decimal(6)  not null,
    Salary    number      null
);
```

In particular, instead of `varchar()` this uses `varchar2()` -- which Oracle recommends for such types.  In addition, `salary` does not use `double`; it uses `number`.  In my experience, monetary amounts should never be stored using floating point representations.

In addition, I question the use of `decimal(6)` for the ids.  In my experience with such ids leading zeros are used.  So, instead of `123` the id would be `000123` -- and everyone's would be the same length.

If that is the case here, then use a string where the values must be digits:

```
employee_UID varchar2(6)  not null primary key check (regexp_like(employee_UID, '^[0-9]{6}$'))
```

If the `6` is arbitrary, then just use `int` or `number`.  There is no need to predefine the length (beyond the storage class for the type).